# mod-rewrite combine two different rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rules:

First Rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

Second Rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/.+)$ module.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The first rule allows me to access /myscript.php as myscript

The second rule allows me to get everything after mydomain.com/ and turn it into a querystring to load module.php?page=querystring.

However, For the first rule if I was to access /myscript/myscript then i get a internal server error. Also I cannot seem to run rule 1 and 2 in the same code. As it seems to conflict. If i go to mydomain.com/myscript/myscript it seems to interfer with the myscript.php and i end up getting a result page=myscript/myscript.php/myscript

Any recommendations on how I can combine the two?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ module.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The fastest gun in the west. Get some sleep!! :)

Comment: @anubhava although it's working, if i have a path that has same name as myscript then i get Internal Server Error. So for example on the root I have a script called myscript.php. So if i go to mydomain.com/myscript it loads the .php file. But if i go to mydomain.com/myscript/ that forwardslash at the end breaks it and i get the error

Comment: @anubhava Thanks. Now if I put a / at the end it works but anything after the fowardslash causes error. So for example if I had a path that had the same name as my script e.g /myscript/users but because myscript.php exists in the route I am still getting 500 error. Also, the re-write where page= only seems to work if i have at least 2 levels of directory, so if i do /level1/ that doesnt work but if i have /level1/level2 then it works

Comment: @anubhava Thanks. It fixed some issues of the page= but now the myscript.php is completely ignored. So in the root I have myscript.php and if i go to /myscript instead of showing me myscript.php it now instead is applying the second rule of loading page=myscript

Comment: @anubhava ah that might explain it. thanks. I will try it in a few hours when i get on my computer.

Comment: @anubhava Many thanks. It does now seem to be working fine.

Comment: @anubhava It worked on my test server but on my actual host it just does not seem to be working. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: @anubhava apologies I thought I couldnt post a comment if i had accepted an answer. I was wrong.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks. On the live server, the myscript is not translating to myscript.php properly it is interring with error 300, but the page= is working as i had to make it like this and add a forwardslash at the front of module.php: RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ /module.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: @anubhava So it seems the problem now is only with RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f It's completely ignoring this condition. I am running the htaccess on the root folder. But it is still completely ignoring it. But the second two conditions for the page= rewrite is working fine. It seems the server has it's own way of loading myscript as myscript.php anyway but not sure how it is doing this and I believe that might be what is conflicting. If I take all the htaccess code out and go to /myscript on the live server, it seems to load myscript.php anyway. So it seems to be skipping the code.

Comment: @anubhava Yes if i use Options -MultiViews then the rule is completely ignore and if i go to /myscript instead of loading myscript, it applies the second rule where it loads module.php?page=myscript But if I take Options -MultiViews out then it doesnt apply the second rule but for some reason the server turns /myscript into /myscript.php instead of the .htaccess doing it.

Comment: @anubhava sorry buddy. Changing it to RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f has made some difference, how i am getting page not found for the .php it is trying to open.

Comment: @anubhava Many thanks. It seems to be working now with the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f I just had to add a forwardslash RewriteRule rule before the $1.php otherwise it wasnt finding the php file. Is this correct?

Comment: @anubhava also, if end the rewrite with [L] it seems to lose all GET parameters. So i changed to [L,QSA] and it now works. So now my rewriterule looks like this: RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php?rewrite=true [L,QSA] - I put rewrite=true so that I can easily debug to make sure it is actually rewriting.

Comment: @anubhava Many thanks buddy, much appreciated. One last question. In the second rule, is the following line needed: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  I am wondering if it's needed since the pattern  ^[^.]+$ already knows that the file doesn't physically exist and the server doesn't have to look for it.

Comment: Yes but technically a filename can be there without extension (dot) also.

Comment: @anubhava Oh, i never thought of that. That's great so it's better to leave it in there. Many thanks once again.